# IDE Shortcut key differences between XE2 and XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

In XE, the action of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click when on a filename declaration in the USES clause  seemed identical - it opened the file in the editor. Now in XE2 it seems that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Click works ok (if the program has been compiled) but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> only works on file names with full path specifications eg:

```
UArtResourceExplorerDlg in '..\..\Paslib32\src\Paslib32\UArtResourceExplorerDlg.pas',
```

If  only

```
UArtResourceExplorerDlg,
```

is specified the IDE cant find it despite the program compiling fine. Is there some additional path information that I should be adding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also noticed this behaviour change and find it very annoying. It forces me to reach for the mouse when I don't want to and never used to.

So far as I can tell there is no way to restore the old behaviour and I suspect that this is in fact a regression in the IDE. One reinforcement for that view is that it used to work for RTL/VCL units and surely there's no need for me to tell the IDE where to find them.

If nobody comes up with a solution then I think it should be reported to Quality Central.

Comment: For the RTL/VCL units, Ctrl-Enter still works IF they are prefixed with the namespace: `Winapi.MMSystem` works while `MMSystem` alone does not. Which more or less is the same as a path... Also worth noting that even with the namespace, code completion (Ctrl-Space) does not work anymore on unit names...

Comment: And yes, I fully agree, it **is** annoying

Comment: @François Perhaps it is intentional to force us to start using these prefixes!!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's valid for XE/XE2, but if the path to the Source file is in the *library* path then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Click will work.  If you want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to work, try ensuring that the path to the source is in the *Browsing* path.  This same thing happens to me in Delphi 6/7.

Comment: I have seen the same behaviour in Delphi2007: Ctrl+Left click works, Ctrl+Enter does not, it opens a file open dialog instead.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Ctrl+Enter is supposed to open the file at the cursor position, while Ctrl+LeftClick does a lookup of the symbol you clicked on, opens the unit that contains its declaration and moves the cursor to the declaration (or in the case of a method to the implemenation) of this symbol.